# What's the most JSON you can reasonably expect to decode on the client side

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

This morning I tried to use ExtJS' JSON decoding facilities against 0.75MB of data, and it crashed FF3.  I'm wondering what is the most JSON one can reasonably expect to decode on the client side? This could be using ExtJS, jQuery, other Javascript frameworks or any built-in decoding that Javascript itself may offer.

Comment: I'd like to keep the emphasis on experience with various Javascript/Frameworks implementations of JSON decoding if at all possible, with "hard and fast" data, particularly if anybody's done any benchmarking.  I'm well aware of alternate approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out Firebug was the culprit.  With it turned off, both Ext.util.JSON.decode and Javascript's native eval() function are returning in 0.15 seconds.

With Firebug on though eval returns in 0.3 whereas I finally got Ext.util.JSON.decode to finish with Firebug on and it took 60+ seconds!!  I definitely need Firebug on during development.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with YUI's JSON parser, so I tried Prototype's JSON parser for large datasets and found it worked a lot better.  I also found that once datasets got to a certain size, they took too long to parse, and the browser would give a message asking if you want to terminate the job.  So for large datasets, it might be worth splitting them up into smaller chunks that are easier to digest.

Comment: Thanks I will be interested if anybody has hard and fast data.  As you say splitting the data is one solution.  So is eval, at least in the short term; eval is finishing in 0.3 seconds on my 0.75 MB of data.

Comment: @George: sending smaller chunks of data will be faster because of wire transmission time too.

Answer (score 1):

This depends largely on the client browser, as Chrome would have no problem with something that large, while IE6 would most likely stop to a halt on the spot.

I'd recommend that instead of a large 750 KB JSON transmission that you'd have to decode at once, try to send smaller (100 KB) messages on the background and requesting/showing the part of the data that the client needs first. That way your page will feel faster. Always try to load on demand large datasets.

My gut feeling is that the problem wasn't with the size of the JSON message anyway, but rather with ExtJS' JSON implementation in FF.

Have you tried this in other browsers? If this happens only on FF, I'd recommend try and use [Firefox's own JSON interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JSON) to do the decoding and see if that works.

Also, have you checked that the JSON response is actually correct? It could be crashing the JSON parser.

Comment: thanks, JSON response is correct as can be inferred from comment in response to Zoidberg, as I am able to eval the JSON response.

Comment: I don't think you're familiar with Ext's implementation.  Please see my answer for details.

Comment: @bmoeskau: I thought so, as most javascript frameworks tend to use the native implementation when possible. Nonetheless, you should not discard a problem with Ext wrapper on FF. If you can use FF's native implementation directly without problems, then you can be certain were the bug lies.

Answer (score 0):

This is interesting since Ext simply uses native browser JSON parsing if supported by the browser, else it `evals` the JSON.  There's no manual parsing of any kind, so not sure how that would be affected by Firebug.  One thing you might try, check the value of `Ext.USE_NATIVE_JSON` just before your parsing logic (should be `true` if you are using FF 3.1+, else will be `false`).  Try setting that to the opposite value and see if that changes anything (again, not sure why it would, but worth trying to see if there is some difference in your case).

BTW, that's an awful lot of JSON... ;)